# Query Analytics api in while loop

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am developing a email marketing dashboard and want to connect my e-mail analytics with Google Analytics.

I have succesfully connected to the Google Analytics api through php and got a revenue for a single email. Now I have a while loop for every mail sent and want to query the Google API per mail in the while loop.

When I insert the query code in the while loop I get an empty page.

I tried using:

**$mailrevenue = getResults($analytics, '126273209', $mailid);**

or:

**return $analytics->data_ga->get(.....**

What is the best way to integrate the Google API query in a while loop?

Comment: I don't think the API client does have a "getResults" function - the function in the examples is just a wrapper around data_ga->get, which in turn requires additional parameters (start and end date, at least one metric and optionally dimensions and filters). You should enable PHPs error reporting, so you get a message instead of empty screens. And running API queries in a while loop might pretty quickly exhaust your API quota, so that is not necessarily a good idea - better download all records with a mail id and then loop through the results (that's faster, too).

Comment: Also if you just get started you should use the new API (v4,https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/) unless you need realtime data.

Comment: Thanks Elke, hadn't thought about the API quota.

I have one array from Analytics and another from my mail system. Just have to figure out how to add the analytics data to the corresponding record in the other array. Both arrays have corresponding values in one column but some values don't exist in both arrays so those have to be left out.